# Silverstripe - Firing a FormAction within CMSFields

Tags: content-management-system, silverstripe

Is it possible to fire a FormAction button from within CMSFields? I'm currently using the following code but the button click doesn't want to fire the form action. Does this need to be called through a custom entwine function or is there something already built in that I'm missing?

```html
class NotesPage extends Page {
 function getCMSFields() {
  $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

  // Page Sections
  $fields->addFieldsToTab('Root.Notes', array(
   // Send for approval
   LiteralField::create('', '<h3>Notify Admin Of Content To Approve</h3>'),
   FormAction::create('NotifyAdmin', 'Notify Admin'),
  ));

  return $fields;
 }
}

class NotesPageExtension extends LeftAndMainExtension {
    private static $allowed_actions = array(
  'NotifyAdmin'
    );

 // Email the admin about content to moderate
 public function NotifyAdmin($data, $form){
  $className = $this->owner->stat('tree_class');
        $SQL_id = Convert::raw2sql($data['ID']);

        $record = DataObject::get_by_id($className, $SQL_id);

        if(!$record || !$record->ID){
            throw new SS_HTTPResponse_Exception(
                "Bad record ID #" . (int)$data['ID'], 404);
        }

        // at this point you have a $record,
        // which is your page you can work with!

        // this generates a message that will show up in the CMS
        $this->owner->response->addHeader(
            'X-Status',
            rawurlencode('Notifying admin')
        );

        return $this->owner->getResponseNegotiator()->respond($this->owner->request);
 }
}
```

Comment: I haven't seen a `FormAction` actually inserted via `getCMSFields` before, normally it is inserted via [`getCMSActions`](http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/class-DataObject.html#_getCMSActions). Can you just use that or do you really need to insert it via `getCMSFields`?

Comment: You could have a look at `SiteTreeURLSegmentField`, that fires an ajax action and checks if the urlsegment is valid. Other possibility is to use BetterButtons module and add a custom action to the DataObject.

Comment: Thanks Turnerj and wmk, it look's like you need to add a new entwine function to handle the onClick. 
I've just put it into the getCMSActions based on the user's group at this stage.